# None output while parsing inside a class

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm kinda new to python and  i'm trying to parse https://rustavi2.ge/ka/schedule <-- website using the following code,the content might be on georgian but i dont think it matters.

 When you  open the page you will see 
07:15 ანიმაცია "სონიკ ბუმი" <- text in front.
via inspect i can see the elements tag and class also but the following code returns only None.I know i'm doing something terribly wrong but cant really figure it out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://rustavi2.ge/ka/schedule')
c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,'html.parser')
a = soup.find("div", {"class": "sch_cont"}).find("div",{"class": "bade_line"})

print((a).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: What is excepted output?

Comment: To be honest I just checked this code and it isn't the right way of doing the task i wanted.Anyway i wanted to have get source code that would help me parsing the content  like time:text,time:text.

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded via Ajax from external site:

```
import requests
import urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://rustavi2.ge/includes/bade_ajax.php?dt=2020-08-17&lang=ka'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tm, title in zip(soup.select('.b_time'), soup.select('.b_title')):
    print(tm.text, title.text)
```

Prints:

```
07:15 ანიმაცია "სონიკ ბუმი"
08:00 მხ/ფილმი
10:00 კურიერი
10:15 სერიალი "ქალური ბედნიერება"
12:00 კურიერი
12:30 სერიალი "ქალური ბედნიერება"
13:55 სერიალი "მე ვიცი რა გელის"
15:00 კურიერი
15:50 დღის კურიერი
16:30 სერიალი "უცხო მშობლიურ მხარეში"
18:00 კურიერი
18:50 სერიალი "მარიამ მაგდალინელი"
20:30 ლოტო
20:40 სერიალი "მარიამ მაგდალინელი"
21:00 კურიერი
22:00 ფარული კონვერტი
23:00 გააცინე და მოიგე
00:00 სერიალი "სენდიტონი"
00:30 მხ/ფილმი
01:00 მხ/ფილმი
03:30 კურიერის დაიჯესტი
04:00 სერიალი "ქალური ბედნიერება"
05:00 სერიალი "უცხო მშობლიურ მხარეში"
```